# Passing parameters to facebook share dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, share

I want to pass in parameters to the facebook share dialog. Currently, the codes below allows me to fix my title, description and website url. however, it does not work for my image. The image doesn't appear at all.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(
    'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=a title&p[summary]=a description &p[url]=http://www.linkhere.com&p[images][0]=http://www.linkhere.com/image.jpg',
    'facebook-share-dialog', 
    'width=626,height=436');
    return false;">
Share </a>
```

Please help!!

Comment: Did you try to use the [OpenGraph protocol](http://ogp.me/) instead? With HTML metas on your targeted page Facebook should automatically populates title/description/image if you only specify the link.

Comment: Hi, i'm going to loop through 2000 data with different images for each set of data. So, each time the user clicks facebook share pertaining to that particular data, it will generate the image that is related to that particular data. I'm not very sure how the HTML metas work and if it's applicable in my case? Do advise!!

btw, thanks for the prompt reply :))

Comment: What I mean is: on page `site.com/flower.html` you will implement the meta image with value `"/images/flower.jpg"`, on `site.com/tree` you will have `"/images/tree.png"`, ... By doing this you don't have to care about the content of the targeted page, you just share a link and Facebook will automatically populates title/description/image in the "Share" dialog. Another advantage of this is that is if someone copy/paste your link in Facebook Facebook will automatically display the correct data (and not a random image and descriptions). Unless I misunderstood something this is applicable to you.